# .htaccess rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help with a rewrite in .htaccess.

I am trying to do the following:
When a user types `http://www.example.com/csc/alabama/`
I need to pull info from `http://www.example.com/csc/index.php?state=alabama`

I thought it should be this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^csc/([^/]*)$ /csc/index.php?state=$1 [L]
```

I keep getting a 404 error.

On a side note, I would like to be able to do this with a generic sub-directory, so that csc could be abc or anything else but this is not the priority.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the trailing slash in your pattern. You should also exclude the destination you are redirecting to:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^csc/([^/]*)/$ /csc/index.php?state=$1 [L]
```